# Relationship between Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem and Convergents

Tags: number-theory, approximation, continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

For any real number $r$, the convergents to the continued fraction expansion of $r$ satisfy Dirichlet's approximation inequality of $|r - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^2}$.

Does this go the other way? That is, if given some rational number $p/q$, we have that $|r - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^2}$, does that necessarily mean that it is a convergent of the continued fraction expansion of $r$?

It does seem, from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations), that we have a similar result that the convergents, and *only* the convergents, minimize $|r - \frac{p}{q}| \cdot q$ among all smaller rationals, so we would need to show that whenever this happens, we also have $|r - \frac{p}{q}| \cdot q < \frac{1}{q}$.

EDIT: Legendre has also proven that if $|r - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{2q^2}$ then $p/q$ is a convergent of $r$. So the main question is what happens if for whatever $p/q$ we have that $\frac{1}{2q} < |r - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q}$: can we determine that $p/q$ is a convergent, or a semiconvergent, or anything at all?

Comment: Legendre proved that if $|r - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{2q^2}$ then $\frac{p}{q}$ is a convergent of $r$. You can find this statement in *Approximation by Algebraic Numbers* of Bugeaud p.10. In the same page, he cited also a result of Fatou that gives you a description of $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $|r - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^2}$ in terms of successive convergents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three results summarize how good continued fractions are at approximating. Here, suppose that $\frac{p_0}{q_0}, \frac{p_1}{q_1}, \frac{p_2}{q_2}, \dots$ are the continued fraction approximants to $r \notin Q$.

1. The statement you quote: for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $|r - \frac{p_n}{q_n}| < \frac1{q_n^2}$.
2. Legendre's theorem: if $|r - \frac pq| < \frac1{2q^2}$, then $\frac pq = \frac{p_n}{q_n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$.
3. Hurwitz's theorem: there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $|r - \frac{p_n}{q_n}| < \frac1{\sqrt5 q_n^2}$. (In particular, there is such a value of $n$ among any three consecutive natural numbers).

However, there are other approximations that are good enough for Dirichlet, but not good enough for Legendre. As pointed out in the comments by @halbaroth, there is a fourth result that characterizes such approximations:

4. Fatou's theorem: if $|r - \frac pq| < \frac1{q^2}$, then $\frac pq \in \{ \frac{p_n}{q_n}, \frac{p_{n+1}+p_n}{q_{n+1}+q_n}, \frac{p_{n+2}-p_{n+1}}{q_{n+2}-q_{n+1}}\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$.

The intuition here is that the continued fraction approximants satisfy the recursion $\frac{p_n}{q_n} = \frac{a_n p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}}{a_n q_{n-1} + q_{n-2}}$. So we often get some extra approximations along the way by replacing $a_n$ with some $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, a_n -1\}$. These are all *okay* approximations, but the only ones that meet Fatou's standards are $k=1$ and $k = a_n - 1$: the ones that are closest to $\frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}$ or $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$.

For example, the first few continued fraction approximants to $\sqrt{2}$ are
$$1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{5},\frac{17}{12},\frac{41}{29},\frac{99}{70},\dots$$
The first few fractions $\frac pq$ with $|\sqrt2 - \frac pq| < \frac1{q^2}$ are
$$1, \frac32, \color{red}{\frac43}, \frac75, \color{red}{\frac{10}7}, \frac{17}{12}, \color{red}{\frac{24}{17}}, \frac{41}{29}, \color{red}{\frac{58}{41}}, \frac{99}{70}, \dots$$
The extra fractions appearing in the gaps are the ones Fatou suggests: for example, $\frac{58}{41} = \frac{41 + 17}{29+12} = \frac{99-41}{70-29}$.

In the case of $\sqrt2$, the error $|\sqrt2 - \frac pq|$ turns out to be approximately $\frac1{2\sqrt2 q^2}$ for the fractions in black and approximately $\frac1{\sqrt2 q^2}$ for the fractions in red, so all of these are good enough.

This does not have to happen; in the case of $\pi$, for example, in between $\frac{22}{7}$ and $\frac{333}{106}$ we have a sequence of approximations $\frac{25}{8}, \dots, \frac{311}{99}$. Fatou promises us only the first and last of these have a chance of being good, but actually, $|\pi - \frac{25}{8}| \approx \frac{1}{0.94 \cdot 8^2}$ and $|\pi - \frac{311}{99}| \approx \frac1{0.57 \cdot 99^2}$: neither is good enough. Fatou does not promise that any of these approximations will satisfy the inequality $|r - \frac pq| < \frac1{q^2}$ - only that nothing else will.

Additionally, the approximations $\frac{p_{n+1}+p_n}{q_{n+1}+q_n}$ and $\frac{p_{n+2}-p_{n+1}}{q_{n+2}-q_{n+1}}$ can, in some cases, get arbitrarily close to the constant of Legendre's theorem. For this, consider $x = 50 + 5\sqrt{102}$: this has continued fraction expansion $[100;2,100,2,100,2,\dots]$. (I hope it is clear how I got this example.) Two consecutive continued fraction approximants to $x$ are $\frac{40601}{404}$ and $\frac{4080300}{40601}$. The first of these is very good: $404^2|x - \frac{40601}{404}| \approx \frac{1}{101}$. The second of these is still decent: $40601^2|x-\frac{4080300}{40601}| \approx \frac1{2.02}$. Well, if we add these together, the result $\frac{4120901}{41005}$ is nearly as good: $41005^2|x - \frac{4120901}{41005}| \approx \frac1{1.98}$.

Comment: Thanks @Misha. I think you are talking about the semiconvergents - I was thinking of spinning that into another question but it's good to see it here. My main question is, suppose we start with the expression $r - p/q$ and computer that for all rationals $p/q$ up to some threshold without looking at the continued fraction expansion at all. What are the necessary *and* sufficient qualities, just from looking at these errors, to say that it is a convergent (or a semiconvergent)? Clearly it is necessary that it is less than $1/q^2$. Also it is sufficient if it is less than $1/2q^2$. (1/2)

Comment: But suppose we have some $p/q$ such that the error is somewhere in between, let's say $1/1.5q^2$, or whatever. Does that let us determine the status of it as either a convergent or a semiconvergent? We know that it passes Dirichlet's first test to be a convergent, but it doesn't pass Legendre's, so what do we make of it? Is it guaranteed to either be a convergent or not be a convergent? (Or a semiconvergent?)

Comment: Lastly are you saying that the semiconvergents also all have $|r - p/q| < 1/q^2$? It seems you're saying the error "usually" less than $1/\sqrt(2)q^2$, so are they "always" also less than 1/q^2$? In other words, does a rational meet Dirichlet's criterion if and only if it's a semiconvergent?

Comment: The error is about $\frac1{\sqrt 2 q^2}$ specifically in the $r = \sqrt2$ example. In general, the semiconvergents could do considerably worse than $1/q^2$. However, I *think* I've seen a result that everything with error between $1/q^2$ and $1/2q^2$ is either a convergent or a semiconvergent, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Fatou proved that if $|r - \frac{a}{b}| < \frac{1}{b^2}$ then $\frac{a}{b}$ belongs to $\{\frac{p_n}{q_n}, \frac{p_{n+1}+p_n}{q_{n+1}+q_n}, \frac{p_{n+2}-p_{n+1}}{q_{n+2}-q_{n+1}}\}$ for some $n$ where $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ is the $n$-th convergent of $r$.

Comment: @halbaroth Thank you, I have added this information to my answer.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Thanks, that update is useful. So to interpret correctly, we are saying that if we have the error less than $1/q^2$, then it is either a convergent, or either the semiconvergent directly before *or* after some convergent. Is this correct?

Comment: Or perhaps I should tag @halbaroth.

Comment: Lastly, ok, so it seems that if the error is less than $1/q^2$, that's necessary but not sufficient to be a convergent, and if it's less than $1/(2q^2)$, that's sufficient but not necessary. Is there some constant $k$ for which $1/(kq^2)$ is both necessary and sufficient? I guess this could also be a different question, but it's kind of easy to imagine looking at these results.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia The example at the end of my question shows that $\frac1{1.98 q^2}$ is still not sufficient, and we can extend it to show that $\frac1{1.99\dots999 q^2}$ is not sufficient.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, ok, I see now. That makes sense. Also, going the other way, I just did a quick Monte Carlo simulation and it looks like convergents can be arbitrarily close to $1/(q^2)$. It looks like, in general, if you want to determine convergent-ness just from the error spectrum on rationals, it seems to be more useful to compare the error of each rational to previous simpler rationals, where we do have necessary and sufficient requirements for being a convergent, rather than comparing it to some absolute reference error like $1/(kq^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is great; I just wanted to summarize in some more succinct terms:

1. The answer to my original question is no. There can be "false positives" for which $|r - p/q| < 1/q^2$, but which are not convergents. One example is, if we're trying to approximate $\log_2(3/2)$, that $10/17$ has the required property but is only a semiconvergent. So this is necessary but not sufficient.
2. I also talked about how if $|r - p/q| < 1/(2q^2)$, then we know we have a convergent. This also does not go the other way, because now there can be "false negatives." Another good example is $24/41$, which is also convergent of $\log_2(3/2)$ but which doesn't have the required property. So this is sufficient but not necessary, and now we get "false negatives" if we are looking for convergents.
3. There is an important result of Fatou which basically says, paraphrasing slightly, that if we do have $|r - p/q| < 1/(2q^2)$, which again is sufficient but not necessary, the "extra" rationals satisfying this property which are not convergents are all semiconvergents that are directly adjacent to some convergent.
4. I was hoping for some magic $k$ such that if the error is less than $1/(kq^2)$, that's necessary and sufficient to make it a convergent. But, it appears that non-convergents can get arbitrarily close to the $1/(2q^2)$ bound, and going the other way, convergents can get arbitrarily close to the $1/(q^2)$ bound.